# Изменение первого элемента линейного списка

Tags: c, list

Написал код :

```
void delete_first(LIST_t** first, int res, int res_end)
{
    LIST_t* swp = *first;
    while (swp->idx_start != res)
    {
        swp = swp->new_ptr;
    }

    LIST_t* element = NULL;
    if (swp->prev_ptr != NULL)
        element = swp->prev_ptr;

    while (swp->idx_end != res_end)
    {
        swp = swp->new_ptr;
        free(swp->prev_ptr);
    }

    if (element != NULL)
        element->new_ptr = swp->new_ptr;
    else
    {
        first = &swp->new_ptr;
        free((*first)->prev_ptr);
    }
}
```

На вход функции поступает указатель на указатель на первый элемент линейного списка, в какой-то момент мне требуется изменить этот первый элемент, но почему-то то, как сделал я не работает. Из-за чего? Изменение всех остальных элементов работает корректно.
Спасибо!

Comment: Если я убираю строчку ```free((*first)->prev_ptr);```, то программа компилируется, но первый элемент все равно остается прежним

Comment: Вы бы словами написали, что именно хотите сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему, но есть НЕБОЛЬШОЕ подозрение, что решение неадекватное))

```
LIST_t* changer = first->new_ptr;
        first->idx_start = first->new_ptr->idx_start;
        first->idx_end = first->new_ptr->idx_end;
        first->word = first->new_ptr->word;
        first->new_ptr = first->new_ptr->new_ptr;
        free(changer);
```